# Remove Whitepixels from a bitmap

Tags: actionscript-3, bitmap, alpha-transparency

I converted a movieclip with a lot of unused space into a bitmap, but it seems alike that many white pixels have been added to the bitmap during the conversion so the background wont be displayed properly.

My question is how to remove the background the smartest way...
remove every single white pixel and if so how to do it?
generate a alphamap from the movieclip if possible how to?
or some other way that I dont know about?

thx in advance =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

refer a following code. this code is if pixel is white color, convert to transparent color.

```
for(var i:int = 0; i<myBitmapData.width; i++)
{
    for(var j:int = 0; j<myBitmapData.height; j++)
    {
        if(myBitmapData.getPixel(i,j) == 0xffffff)
        {
            var transparent:uint = 0x00000000;
            myBitmapData.setPixel32(i, j, transparent);
        }
    }
}
```

you've checked following code. before tested, must stage of change the color to Red or Blue or Green... you want.

```
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.display.BitmapData;
import flash.display.Bitmap;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

var brush:Sprite =new Sprite();
brush.graphics.beginFill(0xffffff);
brush.graphics.drawRect(0,0,100,100);
brush.graphics.endFill();
//addChild(brush);

var myBitmap:Bitmap = new Bitmap(convertToBitmap(brush));
var bmd:BitmapData = myBitmap.bitmapData;
addChild(myBitmap);

for(var i:int = 0; i<bmd.width; i++)
{
    for(var j:int = 0; j<bmd.height; j++)
    {
        if(bmd.getPixel(i,j) == 0xffffff)
        {
            var transparent_color:uint = 0x00000000;
            bmd.setPixel32(i, j, transparent_color);
        }
    }
}

function convertToBitmap( clip:DisplayObject ):BitmapData
{
    var bounds:Rectangle = clip.getBounds( clip );
    var bitmap:BitmapData = new BitmapData( int( bounds.width + 0.5 ), int( bounds.height + 0.5 ), true, 0 );
    bitmap.draw( clip, new Matrix(1,0,0,1,-bounds.x,-bounds.y) );
    return bitmap;
}
```

Comment: thx, thats what I thought about but didnt know how to code, but do you really think this is the fastest / best way?

Comment: i edited post. check out please. you've check this `bmd.setPixel32(...)`.

Answer (score 1):

Another way is when creating your BitmapData object, to use a fill with an ARGB color who's alpha is 0.  This way you don't have to iterate over the BitmapData and set each pixel as in @bitmapdata's answer.

```
var bitmapData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(100, 100, true, 0x00000000);
```

Here's a sample app that shows this in effect:

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Bitmap;
    import flash.display.BitmapData;
    import flash.display.Graphics;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.display.StageAlign;
    import flash.display.StageScaleMode;

    public class TestAS3 extends Sprite
    {
        private var drawingObject:Sprite = new Sprite();
        private var bitmap:Bitmap = new Bitmap();
        private var backgroundObject:Sprite = new Sprite();

        public function TestAS3()
        {
            super();
            stage.scaleMode=StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
            stage.align=StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;

            // draw something on the background, so we can verify the
            // bitmap has transparency
            var g:Graphics = backgroundObject.graphics;
            g.beginFill(0xFF0000);
            g.drawRect(0,0,200,200);
            g.endFill();
            addChild(backgroundObject);

            // draw a black circle so we can make a bitmap out of it
            g = drawingObject.graphics;
            g.beginFill(0);
            g.drawCircle(100,100,50);
            g.endFill();

            // create the bitmap data
            // note use an ARGB color (here color is black, alpha is 0)
            // to default the BitmapData to a transparent fill 
            var bmd:BitmapData = new BitmapData(200,200,true,0x00000000);
            bmd.draw(drawingObject);
            bitmap.bitmapData=bmd;
            addChild(bitmap);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks man =)
I didnt understand it completly but it looks alike it works, gonna play around with that the next minutes! thanks for helping!

Comment: It's really simple (only 1 line), I just added a silly example. When creating the BitmapData, give it a transparent fill instead of the default one.